# 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I use nginX/1.6 and laravel when i posted data to server i get this error 413 Request Entity Too Large. i tried many solutions as bellow

```
1- set client_max_body_size 100m; in server and location and http in nginx.conf.
2- set upload_max_filesize = 100m in php.ini
3- set post_max_size = 100m in php.ini
```

After restarting php5-fpm and nginx the problem still not solved

Comment: Make sure you are not overwriting client_max_body_size values in included config files, that is if your nginx.conf, includes other .conf files.

Comment: i checked all .conf files and ensured that

Comment: i solved the problem by remove client_max_body_size from  location

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Add ‘client_max_body_size xxM’ inside the http section in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, where xx is the size (in megabytes) that you want to allow.

```
http {
      client_max_body_size 20M;         
}
```

Comment: could you give full dir? I can't find it

Comment: I think you need to restart ngnix
`sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: nginx docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Answer (score 16):

I had the same issue but in docker. when I faced this issue, added `client_max_body_size 120M;` to my Nginx server configuration,

nginx default configuration file path is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 120M;
    ...
```

it resizes max body size to 120 megabytes. pay attention to where you put `client_max_body_size`, because it effects on its scope. for example if you put `client_max_body_size` in a **location** scope, only **the location scope** will be effected with.

after that, I did add these three lines to my PHP docker file

```
RUN echo "max_file_uploads=100" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-max_file_uploads.ini
RUN echo "post_max_size=120M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-post_max_size.ini
RUN echo "upload_max_filesize=120M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-upload_max_filesize.ini
```

since docker PHP image automatically includes all setting files from the path (`/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/`) into php.ini file, PHP configuration file will change by these three lines and the issue must disappear

Answer (score 2):

I am using Docker and PHP 7.4 and I faced this issue too.

Just added a line to the file ***.conf** inside **docker/php74/** directory.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ...
}
```

Comment: If you read carefully what AhmedShawky has asked, It seems that he had already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

Even after adding  `client_max_body_size 20M;`  in nginx.conf file, I get the same error in my Laravel app.Later I found the limit referred to in the `php.ini`.
Go to `/etc/php/<your-php-version>/fpm` and edit the following lines in the `php.ini` file .

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 20M
```

increase the limit size as per your app need.Dont forget to Restart PHP-FPM by `sudo service php8.2-fpm restart`