# Nginx: 413 Request Entity Too Large Error

Tags: scala, nginx, request, playframework-2.0

Okay guys, I have followed these answers
[413 Request Entity Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608606/413-request-entity-too-large)

add `client_max_body_size 20M` in nginx.conf and also inside httpd.confd folder which is related with my proxy configuration. I added in http, server and location block. I use Play! Framework as my gateway.

But still, I'd have `Request entity too large error`. Do you guys have any idea or suggestions? Or link to follow through?

Thanks

Comment: Play can also return this response code. What version are you using?

Comment: I use Play 2.11 @m-z

Answer (score 2):

As well as the web servers in front of Play, which it sounds like you have configured, Play itself has max request Content-Length limits, documented here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaBodyParsers#Content-length-limits

> Most of the built in body parsers buffer the body in memory, and some
>   buffer it on disk. If the buffering was unbounded, this would open up
>   a potential vulnerability to malicious or careless use of the
>   application. For this reason, Play has two configured buffer limits,
>   one for in memory buffering, and one for disk buffering.
>
> The memory buffer limit is configured using
>   `play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer`, and defaults to 100KB, while the
>   disk buffer limit is configured using `play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer`,
>   and defaults to 10MB. These can both be configured in
>   application.conf, for example, to increase the memory buffer limit to
>   256KB:

Depending on the situation, you may want to be careful with increasing this limit too much -- if you have untrusted clients they may be able to overload your server by sending lots of very large requests in a short space of time. This may cause your server to crash with an `OutOfMemoryError`, leading to a denial of service attack.

Comment: I've figured it out. Turned out, my Nginx hold it back, even when Play had been increased