# Maximum file upload stays even after editing php.ini

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache2

- Laravel Version: 5.4
- PHP Version: 7.2
- Database Driver & Version: Running Apache2 on ubuntu

#### Description:

So i am trying to upload multiple files in one batch in my website and am getting the maximum payload
reached Error"413 Payload Too Large"
i tested with 20 files each around 2.5M

I Read online that this is related to php settings in the php.ini file located on my server.

I have changed (enlarged) the values of

```
  upload_max_filesize =10M
    post_max_size =310M 
    max_file_uploads=30 
    memory_limit=-1
```

(although -1 is infinite i also tried setting it to large values to test):
in 
the php.ini file in all of :

```
etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini
```

Restarted Apache services
Restarted fpm services
and the error still persists.
I am thinking there might be a setting related to Laravel that i also need to update??

#### Steps To Reproduce:

upload multiple files with big size values

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608606/413-request-entity-too-large) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload large file > 5MB in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600197/how-to-upload-large-file-5mb-in-laravel-5)