# MediaStreamRecorder can't record more than an hour?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-recording, video-conferencing, web-mediarecorder

I am creating a video conference which takes 1 hour. And it can't save because ***Payload Too Large***

Here is my code:

```
const data = [];
multiStreamRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
    data.push(blob);

    var fileName = getFileName('webm');
    var scheduleId = $('#stop-recording').data('id');
    var fileObject = new File([data[0]], fileName, {
        type: data[0].type
    });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(data[0]);

    var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('video_blob', fileObject);
        formData.append('video_filename', fileObject.name);
        formData.append('schedule_id', scheduleId);

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/') }}/store',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            //
        }
    });
};
multiMediaRecorder.start();
```

I need to record the entire conference.

Answer (score 1):

The "*payload too large*" error comes from your server, not from the MediaRecorder API.

You probably have ways to raise that limit in your server's configs.
Alternatively, you could send the final file by chunks, but that's probably sub-optimal.

<sub>Unrelated note:

sending the blobURI is useless, this URI will only be valid for the context that did create it.</sub>

Comment: Oh, okay.. then how can I raise the limits? do you have example on how to send the final file by chunks?

Comment: BlobURI is deleted. But do you have sample snippet on how can I save audio only using MultiStreamRecorder in MediaStreamRecorder? Because I think video is heavier than audio files. So it might be this is the solution.

Comment: Every server will have their own way of setting max-upload-limit. You didn't say anything on your backend, so we can't help. But search for "Error 413"  + the name of your backend, for instance [for apache](https://www.google.com/search?q="Error+413"+apache)

Comment: Sorry, I am using Laravel.

Comment: ... then type *"Error 413" laravel*  in a search engine, this might bring you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608606/413-request-entity-too-large The current question is about the MediaRecorder Web-API, I only answer that.

Comment: Yes, it's working now in my local, but I'm worried with my storage, now I am only recorded 3mins and the fileSize is 15MB. And how about if the videocall takes 1hr.. so bad.. Maybe I need something to change my code to record only audio.

Comment: You are the only one able to answer these design questions. First decide what route you wish to take, then search how to achieve this, and if you don't find, then ask a new question.

Comment: Okay thank you for your help. Maybe my question is not clear.

Comment: The current question is quite clear: "I faced a 413 error, I thus wonder if MediaRecorder can record more than an hour.".  The answer to this question is quite simple: "The error you faced is caused by your server, MediaRecorder doesn't have such limit.". That's a perfectly valid Q/A. That it doesn't really help you fix your issue right now doesn't really matter for SO.