# How can I modify the nginx configuration in Railway?

Tags: laravel, nginx, railway

I'm getting a "413 Request Entity Too Large" when uploading images to my Laravel app deployed with Railway (which is using Nixpacks).

I've seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608606/413-request-entity-too-large) that this can be solved by modifying the "client_max_body_size 20M;" in  in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

However, I can't figure out how can I access this configuration file Railway.

**How can I make such a configuration in Railway?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify nginx configuration using Nixpacks you can create a nginx.conf or nginx.template.conf file in the root folder of your app and add there your configurations. The content of the file for this case would be:

```
worker_processes 5;
daemon off;

worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  # Default: 1024
}

http {
    include    $!{nginx}/conf/mime.types;
    index    index.html index.htm index.php;

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /dev/stdout;
    sendfile     on;
    tcp_nopush   on;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; # this seems to be required for some vhosts


    client_max_body_size 20M;  # Modify this to fit you needs

    server {
        listen ${PORT};
        listen [::]:${PORT};
        server_name localhost;

        $if(NIXPACKS_PHP_ROOT_DIR) (
            root ${NIXPACKS_PHP_ROOT_DIR};
        ) else (
            root /app;
        )

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        index index.php;

        charset utf-8;

        $if(IS_LARAVEL) (
            location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            }
        ) else ()

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        $if(IS_LARAVEL) (
            error_page 404 /index.php;
        ) else ()

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include $!{nginx}/conf/fastcgi_params;
            include $!{nginx}/conf/fastcgi.conf;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
            deny all;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still experiencing problems with the image upload, but this solve the original question.

Fonts:

https://nixpacks.com/docs/providers/php
https://github.com/railwayapp/nixpacks/blob/main/src/providers/php/nginx.template.conf